# Bot Framework v4 - initiate chat with a user ( proactive messages )

Tags: javascript, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I would like to start a conversation with a user without that he already chatted with the bot.

I'm proceeding bu getting the `conversationId` when user install the bot app as [mentionned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#obtain-necessary-user-information)

Here how I catch `reference` and `serviceUrl` by using `processActivity` event

Then I use `continueConversation` + `reference`

```
const {
    BotFrameworkAdapter,
} = require('botbuilder');
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: "xxxx",
    appPassword: "xxxxy"
})
module.exports = async function(context, req) {
    console.log(adapter);
    try {

        adapter.processActivity(req, context.res, async (turnContext) => {
            const reference = turnContext.activity.conversation.id
            const serviceUrl = turnContext.activity.serviceUrl

            await adapter.continueConversation(reference, async (turnContext) => {
                try {
                    await turnContext.sendActivity("this is proacive message");

                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            });

        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
    return;
};
```

I'm getting  this error

> `Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.sendActivity(): missing serviceUrl.`

I have checked the `turnContext.activity` values. I get : 
 `{"type":"event","name":"continueConversation"}"` all other values are undefined ( serviceUrl also )

I noticed that `turnContext.activity`inside `adapter.processActivity` is not the same as in `adapter.continueConversation` and have all the `serviceUrl` and `conversationId`

How can I edit this code example to be able to send proactive messages to users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The const reference needs to be ConversationReference not just the Id if you are using it for BotFrameworkAdapter.continueConversation().

A ConversationReference can be retrieved by using:

```
const reference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(turnContext.activity);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/botframeworkadapter?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#continueconversation-partial-conversationreference----context--turncontext-----promise-void--

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/turncontext?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#getconversationreference-partial-activity--